# MVC JQuery Ajax request doesnt return value but doesnt return error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Here is my front end request

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Testerosa", "Attendance")";
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            debugger; alert(data);
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
```

Here is my controller function

```
        public string Testerosa()
    {
        return "Aubrey";
    }
```

data = "", 
I do not get an error., 
a break in the server side code does not get hit., 
The path is correct.

Spent a day on this so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the url is working fine..(In browser itself directly call the URL and check)

Answer (score 0):

Why you not try out ajax call in following way.

```
function ajaxCall {
            var data = "your data in json format here";
            $.ajax({
                url: "Your url",
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function(data, status, er) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Syntax error
   at parseJSON (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:550:4)
   at ajaxConvert (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:8429:8)
   at done (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:8185:4)
   at callback (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js:8778:8)                    parsererror, 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all javascript ajax code within document.ready function of Jquery.

Change controller method to.

```
public JsonResult Testerosa()
{
    return JSON("Aubrey");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. At least in an MVC environment...
I was testing on a controller that was adorned with [Authorize] tag.
The error I was getting did not indicate this. It showed as a good link, but didn't mention anything about not being authenticated. It just didn't hit the server code. Lesson learned!
Note to anyone having this issue. If you don't care(or you are testing) then adorn your method with [AllowAnonymous] otherwise make sure you are authenticated if your code requires it.
Thanks to everyone.  All answers helped me in getting to my solution. Especially  Sambath Kumar S